# Call NCBI Multiple Sequence Alignment Viewer with target URL?

Tags: multiple-sequence-alignment

I am storing a sequence aligment file on a webserver and now would like to visualize the results. I used the [NCBI Multiple Sequence Alignment Viewer](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/projects/msaviewer/) . The issue is that there are several manual steps involved, that could be streamlined.

1. open the file dialog
2. search the add file or type in the urls
3. click on open

etc.

I wonder if there is a way to call the viewer (or any other alignment viewer) with a single HTTP request, that contains the URL of the alignment file?

Comment: Such functionality hasn't been implemented in NCBI's MSA viewer. This is of interest to the developers of MSA viewer and would appreciate feedback from you. Please consider contacting the devs by using the "Feedback" link present at the top right corner of the [MSA Viewer](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/projects/msaviewer/?url=data/protein.gbp).